# discord py Client.guilds возвращает пустой список

Tags: python, discord.py

Почему вообще такое может быть. Бот на 3 моих серверах

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])
Client = discord.Client()
@bot.command()
async def сервера(ctx):
    servers = Client.guilds
    print(servers)
```

Comment: вы назвали функцию по русски??

Comment: на скольких серверах бот?

Comment: бот на 3 моих серверах, а название функции не влияет (есть много других рабочих)

Comment: @RAINGM бот на 3 серверах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])
@bot.command()
async def сервера(ctx):
    servers = bot.guilds
    print(servers)
```